# In Windows 7 whenever I plug/unplug an external monitor my gamma changes. How can I stop this?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a W540 laptop which uses an optimus setup (NVIDIA K2100M and Intel HD Graphics Family (I would like to once again applaud Intel in coming up with such an obscured/generic name for their video adapter)

A few weeks ago while I was connected a projector (via a mini-displayport to d-sub adapter, as the inherent d-sub in my laptop did not appear to work), I attempted to adjust the gamma on the NVIDIA Control panel to compensate for the poor quality of the projector.

Unfortunately now, every time I plug/unplug an external monitor, the gamma (and possibly other display settings) change to show a washed out colour! So I have to manually reset it in the NVIDIA Control Panel.

I'm guessing this is some sort of mixup between the NVIDIA settings, the Intel Settings, and whatever the hell Windows 7 has as inbuilt settings. But I can't figure out where this is.

The other odd thing is I do not actually CHANGE any settings. I simply have to switch between the settings for them to be reset back to the defaults.

An example of what happens:

1. I plug in an external monitor.
2. I notice my colours are all washed out/high gamma
3. Open the NVIDIA Control Panel
4. In the "Choose how color is set", I change the radio button to 'Use NVIDIA settings'. Then I change it back to 'Other applications control color settings". Note that at no time do I actually CHANGE any settings.
5. At this point the gamma is fixed. I can additionally hit 'restore defaults' or 'apply' to no effect (in the future).

Screenshot of the control panel is below. All I do is move that radio button under section 2.

[image]
Is there a way I can stop this from happening every time I plug/unplug another display?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the external monitors, reboot, connect the monitor to load the drivers and information?

Comment: When you say delete the external monitors do you mean from device manager?

Comment: Yes, so that the system can reload the drivers and default settings.

Comment: Your post is not really clear, every time you plug in the external monitor is it applying the settings you set for the projector to the monitor ? If that's the case it's either Nvidia's processes or intels that are applying those setting. Where did you originally set the settings for the projector? Can't you go back there and change them? You could also see if Intel and Nvidia services are running in the background, and stop those services when you plug in the monitor and see if it still applies the bad settings, if not, you can narrow down which service is applying those and go from there.